# JsonObject in .NET for Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I get a response string from an API by using this code :

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

However I'm unable to find out how to initialize a JsonObject since in .NET for WinRT the constructor JsonObject() doesn't take any arguments. For memory I could have made like that in the "regular" .NET Framework :

```
JsonObject root = new JsonObject(responseText);
```

What I've missed ?

Comment: There is no `JsobObject` in regular .Net Framework. There is one in Silverlight and one in .Net 4.5, but not before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to serialize the response as a [`JsonObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json.jsonobject) you should use `JsonObject.Parse(string)` or `JsonObject.TryParse(string, out JsonObject)` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are truly needing to parse/traverse a JSON encoded string, perhaps all you need to is deserialize it.  Here are Microsoft docs on doing that.

[Deserialize JSON Encoded String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)

I personally like working with Newtonsoft's JSON API for this task.

```
MyObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonEncodedString);
```

[Newtonsoft's JSON API](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly Newtonsoft doesn't yet run on winrt and porting it is non-trivial :/